# Parse mongo DB can not connect to server

Tags: mongodb, parse-platform

I'm trying to setup a parse server on my own machine with mongo DB on the same machine. Following this tutorial, https://medium.com/@dmathewwws/guide-to-building-your-own-parse-server-aad6568b743d

But I'm having some issues with Parse complaining not able to connect to my database.

```
2017-07-22T17:41:39.888Z - Error generating response. { MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect
at Pool.<anonymous> (/parse/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:313:35)
at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
at Pool.emit (events.js:210:7)
at Connection.<anonymous> (/parse/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:260:12)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:318:30)
at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
at Connection.emit (events.js:213:7)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/parse/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:162:49)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:316:30)
at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
name: 'MongoError',
message: 'failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect' }
```

Mongo DB seems to be running on 27017.

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       Inode       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      112        24024       3200/mongod
```

And I can connect through command line too,

```
mongo mongodb://username:pwd@localhost:27017/myDB
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.15
connecting to: mongodb://username:pwd@localhost:27017/myDB
> show collections
test
>
```

And here is my dock file setup.

```
environment:
  ...
  DATABASE_URI: mongodb://username:pwd@localhost:27017/myDB
mongo:
  image: mongo:3.2.15
  expose:
    - "27017"
  volumes:
    - /mnt/database/mongodb
```

The mongodb actually sits in an another volume, with this permission.

```
root@test:/mnt/database# ls -lh
total 20K
drwx------ 2 root    root     16K Jul 20 02:34 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x 4 mongodb mongodb 4.0K Jul 22 17:10 mongodb
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to replace localhost with container links. I found this  [tutorial](https://medium.com/@levioza/setup-a-parse-server-in-a-few-minutes-using-docker-compose-c81825c27a4) helpful.

```
parse-server: 
    ...
    environment:
      ...
      DATABASE_URI: mongodb://mongo:27017/myDB
    links:
        - mongo:mongo
mongo:
  image: mongo
  volumes:
    - /mnt/database/mongodb
```

**TLDR:** [tutorial](https://medium.com/@levioza/setup-a-parse-server-in-a-few-minutes-using-docker-compose-c81825c27a4): docker-compose.yml

```
mongo-parse-server:
    image: mongo
parse-server:
    image: yongjhih/parse-server
    links:
        - mongo-parse-server:mongo
    environment:
        - APP_ID=LWP_APP
        - MASTER_KEY=DA5AC2FF-8F44-4082-8E5C-A78F2A96ACAD
        - FILE_KEY=1DAFE373-5D8A-4E7A-AD05-67C3BA0EDB64
    ports:
        - 1337:1337
parse-dashboard:
    image: yongjhih/parse-dashboard
    environment:
        - PARSE_DASHBOARD_CONFIG={"apps":[{"appId":"LWP_APP","serverURL":"http://192.168.99.100:1337/parse","masterKey":"DA5AC2FF-8F44-4082-8E5C-A78F2A96ACAD","appName":"LWP"}],"users":[{"user":"foo","pass":"bar"}]}
        - PARSE_DASHBOARD_ALLOW_INSECURE_HTTP=1
    ports:
        - 4040:4040
```

Comment: Note: Don't post your App keys on Stackoverflow

Comment: Thanks, the key was a copy/paste from the tutorial

Comment: I see. There's also advanced usage on Github. https://github.com/yongjhih/docker-parse-server/blob/master/ADVANCE.md